# "Пустой" ответ на ajax запрос

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, cookie, request

Вот допустим мне пришел `Ajax` запрос на метод который возвращает `PartialView`. Еще по условию этот `PartilView` должен будет полностью заменить контент в элементе с таким-то `id`. А если во время обработки `Ajax-запроса` на сервере, я обнаружил, что в запросе ошибка(нет таких данных в бд, или строка не прошла проверку на корректность, нет куки), то как сделать так, чтобы браузер получил ответ, но контент не изменял?
Конечно, в некоторых случаях можно просто вернуть контент по-дефолту(как при обычном запросе к странице), но в таком случае мне придется "предполагать" о состоянии пользователя, что не очень хорошо.
P.S. будет ли при `Ajax-запросе` работать перенаправление на другой `Action`?(`RedirectToAction("action","controller")`). Т.е. как бы браузер просто хотел обновить контент, а тут его просят перейти по другому адресу.

Comment: А что мешает вернуть пустую строку, а в js проверить, что же вернул php?

Comment: А по-хорошему, возвращают json, в котором кроме самой информации , ещё и статус ответа.